# How to print stdout immediately?

Tags: ruby, io, stdout, stdin

How can I immediately output `stdout`? `stdout` is going to print after all input is complete.

```
require 'open3'
def run(cmd)
    Open3.popen3(cmd) do |stdin, stdout, stderr, thread|

    Thread.new do
      stdout.each {|l| puts l}
    end

    Thread.new do
      while thread.alive?
        stdin.puts $stdin.gets
      end
    end

    thread.join
  end
end

run ("ruby file_to_test.rb")
```

file_to_test.rb:

```
puts "please, enter s"
puts "please, enter q"

s = gets.chomp!
q = gets.chomp!

puts s
puts q
```

The result after running main.rb is:

```
somestring
somestring2
please, enter s
please, enter q
somestring
somestring2
```

How can I immediately output `stdout`?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for [flush](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/IO.html#method-i-flush)?

Comment: @pjs yes,I saw this, but it doesn't want to work,or I used it incorrect...

Comment: You placed a `$stdout.flush` or `STDOUT.flush` after each `print` or `puts`?

Answer (score 34):

Ruby is buffering output until the output buffer is full. To change the behavior so it automatically writes use [`sync`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/IO.html#method-i-sync) and [`sync=`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/IO.html#method-i-sync-3D):

```
old_sync = $stdout.sync
$stdout.sync = true

puts "immediately output lotsa stuff"
puts "immediately output lotsa stuff"
puts "immediately output lotsa stuff"
puts "immediately output lotsa stuff"

# reenable the default behavior
$stdout.sync = old_sync
```

From the documentation for `sync=`:

> Sets the “sync mode” to true or false. When sync mode is true, all output is immediately flushed to the underlying operating system and is not buffered internally.

It's important to understand that enabling automatic flushing of the buffer can actually slow the overall execution speed of your code, especially if you're writing to a file or device that wants to receive its data in chunks. Use `sync` or flushing carefully.

Answer (score 12):

### Flush the output

What you are looking for is to flush the io stream by using the flush method.

Try the following after each iteration or each puts:

```
stdout.flush
```

If you had multiple puts in a row, I would suggest doing a flush after the last one, so you do not do it too often. Example:

```
stdout.puts "Hello"
stdout.puts "Mate"
stdout.flush
```

Comment: Oh man, you will not believe, but I forgot press Ctrl-S before running ruby-code and I think this solution doesn't work. Now I tries again and it is working )